# Concatenate inside CSS background url

Tags: php, css

I have css like this :

```
<?php echo "<div style='background-image: url(images/$hb1[img_name]);' >"; ?>
```

I want to concatenate the variable inside background url and the css become like this :

```
<?php echo "<div style='background-image: url('images/$hb1[img_name]');' >"; ?>
```

How could I to do that ?

Comment: Is `/$hb1` a directory(folder)? What exactly is the variable in that value? Is it `gambar?` The syntax is confusing... $ and [ ]...?

Comment: @Antonio are you talking about php?

Comment: `$hb1[img_name]` is a image name and I get it from query result @zer00ne

Comment: it's css inside html div tag and the variable `$hb1[img_name]` is from php query result @ha_ryu

Comment: Then you should add PHP tag and include that in your question.

Comment: be careful about using single quotes inside your background image url when your style attribute is also using single quotes, (either escape the url ones, or use double quotes somewhere). also, if that value is coming from PHP try: `<div style="background-image: url('images/<?php echo $hb1['img_name']; ?>');" >`

Comment: @haxxxton I just updated my questions.

Comment: @zer00ne I just updated my questions.

Comment: are you asking how to add quotes inside the url part of the css? (thats the only difference i can see between your code examples). i dont think you're correctly passing the PHP variable value to your html currently.. previous "be careful" warnings still apply

Comment: yes, I want to add quotes inside background url bracket. @haxxxton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make this a bit simpler and just echo what you need to in php e.g

```
<div style="background-image: url('images/<?php echo $hb1['img_name']; ?>')">
```

I noticed in your original code you didn't have any quotes around you array key so this could have been an issue for you. So to take your original code it would be

```
<?php echo "<div style=\"background-image: url('images/".$hb1['img_name']."');\" >"; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this :

```
<?php
$inlineImagePath = "background-image: url('images/".$hb1[img_name]."')";
 echo '<div style="$inlineImagePath"; />'
?>
```